# Save Credit Card Information On Stripe to Send payment later

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, stripe-payments

I am looking at how to send the Credit card information on WooCommerce checkout to be stored in the stripe user account so I can charge later. Like a user goes to my e-commerce and doesn't pay anything at the checkout but it asks for the credit card information, that information will be stored in the stripe account and later I can send payments to that credit card, and values may be variable.

This e-commerce will be selling a program that will charge users based on their usage so I will only know the value later and also send the payment later.

Does anyone know how to do that with the stripe plugin or settings?

Comment: Stripe supports future payments and documents this here https://stripe.com/docs/payments/save-and-reuse You might want to contact WooCommerce's own support team directly to ask how this works with their plugin.